# Knockout button click binding as an attribute

Tags: knockout.js

I've been trying to databind a click event as an attribute in a button using knockout but finding it hard to get it working.

```
<button data-bind="attr:{click :test }">Test1</button>


function ViewModel() {

       self.test = function ( data  ) {
       alert('hit me!');
       }
};


var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Isn't click binding supposed to be working with attr binding or am I missing something obvious here ?

Comment: Button tag has no click attribute. Click is event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an attribute:

```
<button data-bind="click :test, attr: { id: 'theId' }">Test1</button>
```

Comment: I'm aware of directly doing click binding but unfortunately it doesnt help here. I need to data-bind another attribute apart from click.

Comment: Ah, then you do them separately. Like this.

Comment: Doh! I missed that. Thanks!